# How to select and scroll a specific line in GtkSource

Tags: python, gtk3

After reading and trying a lot of ideas, including several suggestions from SO, I still haven't found a working method to scroll to a specific line in a GtkSource.View, after loading a file.

I'm using Gtk-3, introspection, and Python 3. I've tried many combinations of `get_iter_at_line`, `place_cursor`, `place_cursor_onscreen`, and others. Even tried to more or less calculate the scroll position and manipulate the `vadjustment`s.

An example:

```
    itr = self.tbff.get_iter_at_line(linenr)
    self.tbff.place_cursor(itr)
    self.tview.place_cursor_onscreen()
```

I suspect that the problem may come from the fact that the widget has not been rendered yet. I also tried to defer the actual scroll to GLib.idle_add, but that didn't work out either. In just one combination, I found that the widget scrolled to line 55 or so, when I tried to reach line 124:

```
def go_to_line_number(self, linenr):
    itr = self.tbff.get_iter_at_line(linenr)
    mark = Gtk.TextMark(
                name = "exec_point",
                left_gravity = True)
    self.tbff.add_mark(mark, itr)
    self.tview.scroll_mark_onscreen(mark)
```

*Yet another interesting bit*: I thought that delaying the `scroll_mark_onscreen` from the last example might solve it (by using `GLib.timeout_add`). It does! But the time is unreasonable. At 300 ms it still doesn't scroll to the mark, but at 400 ms it works. I don't think it's the file length (only 250 lines), so I suspect it might be the scroll animation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

John

Comment: You use FileLoader, right? Is it guaranteed, that `go_to_line_number` is called after FileLoader`s `.load_finished()`?

Comment: Also you should use `Gtk.TextView.scroll_to_iter`. Because `place_cursor_onscreen` __moves the cursor__ to the currently visible region